# How do I select the Count(*) of an nHibernate Subquery's results

Tags: sql, nhibernate, subquery

I need to do the following for the purposes of paging a query in nHibernate:

```
Select count(*) from 
(Select e.ID,e.Name from Object as e where...)
```

I have tried the following,

```
select count(*) from Object e where e = (Select distinct e.ID,e.Name from ...)
```

and I get an nHibernate Exception saying I cannot convert Object to int32.

Any ideas on the required syntax?

**EDIT**

The Subquery uses a distinct clause, I cannot replace the e.ID,e.Name with `Count(*)` because `Count(*) distinct` is not a valid syntax, and `distinct count(*)` is meaningless.

Answer (score 18):

NHibernate 3.0 allows Linq query.

Try this

```
int count = session.QueryOver<Orders>().RowCount();
```

Comment: The QueryOver extension is not actually the Linq provider, but good option for getting a count

Answer (score 17):

```
var session = GetSession();
var criteria = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Order))
                    .Add(Restrictions.Eq("Product", product))
                    .SetProjection(Projections.CountDistinct("Price"));
return (int) criteria.UniqueResult();
```

Answer (score 2):

Solved My own question by modifying Geir-Tore's answer.....

```
 IList results = session.CreateMultiQuery()
        .Add(session.CreateQuery("from Orders o").SetFirstResult(pageindex).SetMaxResults(pagesize))
        .Add(session.CreateQuery("select count(distinct e.Id) from Orders o where..."))
        .List();
    return results;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a draft of how I do it:

Query:

```
public IList GetOrders(int pageindex, int pagesize)
{
    IList results = session.CreateMultiQuery()
        .Add(session.CreateQuery("from Orders o").SetFirstResult(pageindex).SetMaxResults(pagesize))
        .Add(session.CreateQuery("select count(*) from Orders o"))
        .List();
    return results;
}
```

ObjectDataSource:

```
[DataObjectMethod(DataObjectMethodType.Select)]
public DataTable GetOrders(int startRowIndex, int maximumRows)
{
    IList result = dao.GetOrders(startRowIndex, maximumRows);
    _count = Convert.ToInt32(((IList)result[1])[0]);

    return DataTableFromIList((IList)result[0]); //Basically creates a DataTable from the IList of Orders
}
```

Comment: the problem stems from the fact that I need a Count(*) of the distinct results of the first query, as a count(*) within the query does not produce the same number (3 results vs 54 results due to several joins.)

Answer (score 0):

If you just need `e.Id`,`e.Name`:

`select count(*) from Object where`.....

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add the stipulation that the subquery was distinct.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer,

```
    public IList GetOrders(int pageindex, int pagesize, out int total)
    {
            var results = session.CreateQuery().Add(session.CreateQuery("from Orders o").SetFirstResult(pageindex).SetMaxResults(pagesize));

            var wCriteriaCount = (ICriteria)results.Clone());

            wCriteriaCount.SetProjection(Projections.RowCount());

            total = Convert.ToInt32(wCriteriaCount.UniqueResult());


            return results.List();
    }
```