# Castle/ Active Records: How do you count objects?

Tags: .net, sql, nhibernate, castle-activerecord

I'm trying to do a simple "Select Count(*) from PRODUCTS where date > xxx" with Castle on NHibernate.

If I was directly using NHibernate, I could reuse [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116188/how-do-i-select-the-count-of-an-nhibernate-subquerys-results) answers but unfortunately I see no easy way to access the Current NHibernate session from Castle Records.

I obviously don't want to retrieve all my objects and do a Count on the C# side ;). I only need to know how many objects there are.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are many ways to do this, the simplest is:

```
ActiveRecordMediator<Product>.Count(Expression.Gt("date", DateTime.Now))
```

or your could use CountQuery, HQL, etc, there are many alternatives.

UPDATE: for NHibernate 2.0+ it's `Restrictions` instead of `Expression`.

I'll copy common questions like these to the [ActiveRecord wiki](http://using.castleproject.org/display/AR/FAQ).

Comment: Count is marked as internal so I can't use it in my business layer (I don't really wish to reimplement it on the DAL side). The second one works perfectly, thanks!

Comment: You're right, although it is kind of weird that it's internal... I'll edit the answer, thanks.

Comment: Which Expression class it this? I haven't found it.

Comment: @ripper234: Expression has been renamed to Restrictions in NHibernate 2.0